# Assigning value to specific cell in 2d list not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the below code, which im expecting to cycle over each cell in the 2d list and assign a random value, however looking at the list once complete it seems to assign the same value value for a whole column... For the life i me i cant see whats wrong.

```
    rows, cols = (32, 16) 
    ADCResult = [[0]*cols]*rows

    vChannel = 0
    while vChannel < 16:
        hChannel = 0
        while hChannel < 16:
            ADCResult[hChannel][vChannel] = round(random.uniform(0.2,10.0), 2)
            hChannel += 1

        h2Channel = 0
        while h2Channel < 16:
            ADCResult[h2Channel+16][vChannel] = round(random.uniform(0.2,10.0), 2)
            h2Channel += 1

        vChannel += 1


    for row in ADCResult:
        for element in row:
            print(element ,end='\t')
        print('\n')
```

However this outputs for example

> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14
>
> 7.14    0.42    4.53    2.68    6.55    3.71    7.43    9.05    5.6     3.84    5.62    7.12    0.73    1.38    1.72    3.14

Comment: `ADCResult = [[0]*cols]*rows` - root of the problem.